# why can open mysql in wamp and can't open phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have installed wampserver2.5 in my local pc.
When i input `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`  or  `http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/`  in firefox,it run into errors.

[image]
[image]

I can enter mysql console via wamp ,why i can not enter phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

You should set the MySQL password and account in the phpMyAdmin config file (usually config.inc.php). Then reload phpMyAdmin.